# Eloquent querying with relationship

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

So my problem is pretty simple. I am trying to query a table in a relationship with another using an constrained eager loading.

But for some reason, the constraint is not working.

Here is the code:

```
$top_prospects = Player::with(array('statistic' => function($query){
                                $query->where('carrer_gp', '<=', 41);
                    }))
                    ->where('rights', '<=', '30')
                    ->orderBy(DB::raw('floor(potentiel)+(consistency/10)'), 'desc')
                    ->take(25)
                    ->paginate(5,array('players.id','name','main_position','age','rights','country','potentiel','consistency'));
```

The `carrer_gp <= 41` where is not being respected...

Any ideas why?

Thanks,
Ara

Comment: Check your Eloquent relationship models (hasOne, hasMany, belognsTo, Etc).

Comment: Can you be more specific - what do you expect to happen, what is actually happening?  I would expect to see all players whose rights <= 30, and for each player only the statistics whose carrer_gp <= 41.

Comment: I need it to select everyone who has carrer_gp <=41 AND whose rights <=30....